# Add a part of a UI element as a step for introjs() tutorial

Tags: r, shiny, intro.js

Is it possible to add a part of a UI (e.g., the filter section of a renderDataTable) to intro steps when using introjs()?

Example:
I want the user to know that they can use the filter section of the table to filter results. So as an additional step, I want to highlight the filter part of the datatable as one of the steps of the tutorial.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(rintrojs)

ui <- fluidPage(
    introjsUI(),  # include introjs
    div(id = "intro", h3("Intro")),
    dataTableOutput("my_table")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$my_table <- renderDataTable({
        datatable(iris, filter = 'top')
    })
    
    # Trigger introjs on app start
        introjs(session, options = list(steps = list(
            list(element = "#intro", intro = "Intro"),
            list(element = "#my_table", intro = "This is the table. Now zooming in on filters...")
        )))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add any valid `CSS` selector, thus all you need is to find a proper way to address the row containing the filter elements. Additionally, as the data table is rendered dynamically, you should not call your `introjs` too early, otherwise the element you are trying to target are not yet existing. A good option is to call the `introjs` the first time the system is flushed, where the data table is already populated.

Putting everything together, the following snippet implements the feature:

```r
# Trigger introjs on app start but not before the system is flushed
session$onFlushed(function() {
  introjs(session, options = list(steps = list(
    list(element = "#intro", intro = "Intro"),
    list(element = "#my_table", intro = "This is the table. Now zooming in on filters..."),
    ### :nth-of-type will select the second row (<tr>), that is where the filters are
    list(element = "tr:nth-of-type(2)", intro = "Here you can apply filters")
  )))
})
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I had multiple tables so I just needed to add table ID at the beginning of element, and that worked really well:
`list(element = "#my_table tr:nth-of-type(2)")`